# Unable to update my app through market play

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, sha1

Lets say I'm releasing my app through developer console.
At the same time, the same app I'm installing through android studio on my phone. Everything is ok.
When release is ready and published, I cannot update my app. The error is:
Can't install the app.
Try again or see common ways to fix it...

On the other way, if I uninstall my app and install from google play - its works but signing in cause to error.
Installing from android studio above this version cause to error:

*The device already has an application with the same package but a different signature. In order to proceed, you will have to uninstall the existing application  WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!  Do you want to uninstall the existing application?*

All Sha-1 signatures are updated... Don't know what to do.
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right answer that worked for me, that I get from Firebase support. So easy.

> I have inspected your account and found that your API key for Android is restricted. One thing to keep in mind is that a SHA fingerprint mismatch can cause an app to fail in the production environment.
>
> Please try by removing (temporarily) the API key restriction for android, then wait 5 minutes and check whether the problem persists.
>
> If the app works with the restriction off, make sure that the SHA-1 registered in your API key restriction is the same as the fingerprint of your release key. If you are using Play App signing, please also add the SHA-1 given by App Signing to your restriction.

Answer (score 0):

When you install through AS to debug, you use the debug signing key.  This isn't the same (by default) as your release signing key.  So you get these types of problems.  Your two solutions are:

1)Live with it.  That's what most people do.  This means when swapping from debug to a release build on the same device, you'll need to uninstall and reinstall.

2)Use the same key to sign debug as you do release.  The problem with this is you require all of your devs to have the release key, which is a security risk (they could sign anything they want with that key).  It's not recommended unless this is a 1 developer app.

Comment: Gabe Sechan, but you cannot update debug key, its created automatically. How do you suggest to switch it?

Comment: You can.  It's a file on disk.  Simply replace the file.  It's only created if one doesn't exist

Comment: Replace google-service.json file?

Comment: THe debug store is a keystore file.  It has nothing to do with google-services.  On a mac it's in ~/.android/debug.keystore

Comment: Ok, thanks for it, I will check soon!

Comment: After updating/deleting the debug.keystore, the next time you build and run your Android app in debug mode through Android Studio, it will automatically generate a new debug.keystore for you. 
SO, this method will not help, Gabe.

Comment: @DimaBokov I do this all the time.  It does not.  In fact I can prove it doesn't-  if it generated a new keystore each time, it wouldn't be able to install a new version of the app without uninstalling the old one, which would cause you to lose all data

Comment: Ok, Gabe, I will check it!